# SSL error in Magento

Tags: ssl, magento

I have activated SSL in live magento store.If i check this url https://www.rave-nation.com/index.php, i m getting this error "This Connection is Untrusted".I can't figure out the solution.Do you need more information to find the solution?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827125/why-do-browsers-show-ugly-errors-for-untrusted-ssl-certificates

Answer (score 2):

The SSL certificate you've installed is:

- Self signed
- Signed for `https://localhost`, not `https://www.rave-nation.com`

SSL certificates serve two purposes.  The first is a means to encrypt the data being transferred between the client and the server.  The second is functioning as a method of verifying the identity of the server you are contacting.

Certificates that are self-signed will always generate warnings to people visiting your site because the certificate has not been signed by a high authority.  The higher authority, called a CA, *vouch* for your server being the server your visitor thinks it is.

Anyone could create an SSL certificate for the domain `https://mail.google.com`, for example, and self sign it.  If I was to trick someone's browser to take them to my server instead of Google's when they enter `https://mail.google.com` in their address bar they'd get an error message saying that the connection is *untrusted*.  This appears because the person that signed the certificate, me this case, was not trusted in the first and didn't have the authority to vouch for anyone else, as far as the web browser was concerned.

Using a certificate signed for one hostname, in your case `localhost`, on a website that uses another hostname, `rave-nation.com`, is warning the visitors that this server is claiming to be someone it is not.